# Cropping an image reduces image quality

Tags: opencv

I want to crop a region of interest from an image.
Image: [image]]

I use a function that rotates and crops the region of interest. However, there is a difference in the cropped image output of this function and the manually cropped(via a photo editor or paint) image. 
The rotated image is as follows 
[image]The manually cropped image(with the rotated image as input) is as follows
[image]

The image which I obtained from the function is as follows [image]

You can see the difference. The edges are not sharp and well defined in the case of the function output. How do I solve this problem?

The function is as follows

```
def crop_minAreaRect(img, rect):

    # rotate img
    angle = rect[2]
    rows,cols = img.shape[0], img.shape[1]
    M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((cols/2,rows/2),angle,1)
    img_rot = cv2.warpAffine(img,M,(cols,rows))
    cv2.imshow("img_rot", img_rot)

    # rotate bounding box
    rect0 = (rect[0], rect[1], 0.0)
    box = cv2.cv.BoxPoints(rect)
    pts = np.int0(cv2.transform(np.array([box]), M))[0]    
    pts[pts < 0] = 0

    # crop
    img_crop = img_rot[ pts[1][1]:pts[0][1], pts[1][0]:pts[2][0] ]

    cv2.imshow("cropped", img_crop)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if you are following the same procedure to crop, why the 2 cropped images have different size?

Comment: Is the quality actually reduced or is the image just stretched because you used a different size rectangle?

Comment: @KadiSoheib I am not using the same procedure to crop. I have cropped one barcode manually and the other barcode has been cropped from the function.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds What do you mean by a different sized rectangle?

Comment: You need to give more info in this post. What does the original image look like? Why are you using functions from the deprecated `cv2.cv` module? What do the intermediate steps look like? I also don't understand what the problem is with the second image, is it just the stretch that it has?

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds The image looks like [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yWcGmdxUIGIV0xePOwun62Di9nMMPC1E/view?usp=sharing) after the rotation step. I'm using BoxPoints function and have opencv 2.9 and it gives me an error if I just use cv2.Boxpoints like [this](http://answers.opencv.org/question/36643/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-boxpoints-in-249/). I am finding an ROI which I need to crop. Yes, the edges are not sharp. If I try to sharpen, I may lose some information which I don't want.

Comment: Please add intermediate images into your question, not as links into a comment. Question: Are you rotating the red border as well? (Your final result looks like you do) You should only draw this box for visualization, not into any images which are further processed.

Comment: @chtz Thank you so much for giving me a hint. I was not able to detect my barcodes because of the red borders and all this time I was thinking it was because of the unsharp edges of the barcode. It all works fine now. Thanks again!

Comment: @SurabhiVerma So in the end, the difference is just the colored bounding box? A bad asked question that only you was able to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I wished more clarifications on how you did cropped the image "manually". But since you replied to my comment with same words from your question, I am going to answer here based on guess only.

First let us see what your function does.
From signature `def crop_minAreaRect(img, rect):` it accept an image and a rectangle that defines where to crop. It defines also a **rotation**. The function uses that rotation and transform the image using it so it.
Your question is why the cropped manually and the cropped using this function are different. But first how did you cropped manually? What is the procedure? did you follow the same steps? how did you "manually" rotated the image?
**My guess** here is that you cropped the rectangle from the image first, then the image has undergone many transforms before using this function to crop. If this is true, it explains everything. Of course you will not have same region pixel by pixel and value by value. The only way to get the same rectangle after a rotation is when rotation is 0, 90, 180 or 270 degrees. The reason is interpolation.

Comment: Oh sorry, I cropped the rotated image using a photo editor like [this](https://www169.lunapic.com/editor/?action=crop)

Comment: @SurabhiVerma So you should ask software provider how they are doing the rotate and warp, what formulas are they using and also what libraries are used. No one can give an answer to your question.

Comment: No, I rotated the image using my function and then just cropped the region of interest with this editor.

Comment: @SurabhiVerma which is having less quality, the manually cropped using software?

Comment: no, the manually cropped one has better quality when compared to the one that I obtain from the function

Comment: Your guess in the answer provided is incorrect. I have rotated the image, and I then try cropping on this new image, both from the photo editor and the function.

Comment: @SurabhiVerma OK. no problem if I'm wrong. You can update your question and include precise information on how you got both cropped images in detail. In fact, I still don't get what you did exactly. Your function is clear but what is the input? Also, what was the input to software and what are steps? Please, edit and update your question with missing information.